# Cin messing up SetConsoleTitle

Tags: c++

Im attempting to use a random string generator and set it as my console title. It works but everytime I open the program it only generates 1 character. I finally figured out that it was the cin statement causing it to only generate 1 character.
Ive tried alternatives like getline but hasn't worked.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "injector.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <cstdio>

enum InjectionType : int
{
    ManualMap,

};

InjectionType InjectionMethod;
string proccessname;
string dllname;



using namespace std;

static const char alphanum[] =
"0123456789"
"!@#$%&=+-"
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

int stringLength = sizeof(alphanum) - 1;

char genRandom() {

    return alphanum[rand() % stringLength];
}


int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    string _T(random);
    int length = 30;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        (random) += genRandom();
        SetConsoleTitle(random.c_str());
        InjectionMethod = ManualMap;
        cout << "DLL Name :";
        cin >> dllname;
        }

    std::getchar();
    }
```

Btw sorry for really bad spaghetti code, im pretty new to c++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you see only 1 `char` in the title is because you have `std::cin` inside the loop and after 1st run it holds waiting for your input. Move it outside of the loop or try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <random>

enum InjectionType : int
{
    ManualMap
};

InjectionType InjectionMethod;
std::string proccessname;
std::string dllname;

static const char alphanum[] =
"0123456789"
"!@#$%&=+-"
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

char genRandom()
{
    return alphanum[rand() % (sizeof(alphanum) - 1)];
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));

    size_t length = 30;
    std::string s(length, 0);
    for (auto &c : s)
        c = genRandom();

    SetConsoleTitleA(s.c_str());
    InjectionMethod = ManualMap;

    std::cout << "DLL Name :";
    std::cin >> dllname;
}
```